# Realm React Native - does SORT DISTINCT actually work?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

The [Realm JavaScript documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest#filtering) says:

Sorting and find distinct values are possible with functions SORT and DISTINCT, e.g. age > 20 `SORT(name ASC, age DESC) DISTINCT(name)`.

- The ordering for sorting can be one of the following case insensitive literals: ASC, ASCENDING, DESC, DESCENDING.
- Any number of properties can appear inside the brackets in a comma separated list.
- Any number of sort/distinct conditions can be indicated, they will be applied in the specified order.
- Sort or distinct cannot operate independently, these conditions must be attached to at least one query filter.

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
realm
  .objects<CardFace>(CardFaceSchema)
  .filtered(`SORT(name ASC, expansion.releaseDate DESC) DISTINCT(name)`)
```

And get the red screen of death with the following message: `SORT(name ASC, expansion.releaseDate DESC) DISTINCT(name):1:4(4): Invalid predicate.`

What am I doing wrong? My realm version is 2.3.3

Comment: `name` has index on it, right?

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to post the whole schema for brevity.

Answer (score 14):

Sort and Distinct can't be applied without a predicate. So modify your filter to:

```
realm
  .objects<CardFace>(CardFaceSchema)
  .filtered(`TRUEPREDICATE SORT(name ASC, expansion.releaseDate DESC) DISTINCT(name)`)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. For whatever reason, that was not immediately obvious in the docs. I've moved on to another task, but when I circle back to this, I'll mark this as the answer assuming I don't run into other issues.

Comment: This is what the fourth bullet was designed to convey. I'll circle back with the JavaScript team at Realm to make it more explicit.